# footnotes at the bottom of the page

Tags: footnotes

At this time footnotes are displayed at the end of the text when the text does not fill the entire page. I would like the footnotes to always show at the bottom of the page.

I use rmarkdown and mardown format to create footnotes in a document with `\documentclass{article}`

Code rmarkdown:

```
---
title: "title"
author: "author"
date: '9999-99-99'
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_md: true
    keep_tex: true
    number_sections: true
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_width: 10
    fig_height: 9
    dev: 'svg'
    includes:
     before_body:
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
header-includes:
geometry:
- top=2cm
- bottom=1.5cm
- right=1.0cm
- left=1.0cm
graphics: yes
documentclass: article
papersize: a4
lang: es
always_allow_html: yes
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
---

\section{Introduction}
Nota[^1]

[^1]: Nota
\newpage
```

code latex:

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[
  spanish,
  a4paper,
]{article}
\title{title}
\author{author}
\date{9999-99-99}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={title},
  pdfauthor={author},
  pdflang={es},
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=1.5cm,right=1.0cm,left=1.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
% Set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\ifXeTeX
  % Load polyglossia as late as possible: uses bidi with RTL langages (e.g. Hebrew, Arabic)
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage[]{spanish}
\else
  \usepackage[main=spanish]{babel}
% get rid of language-specific shorthands (see #6817):
\let\LanguageShortHands\languageshorthands
\def\languageshorthands#1{}
\fi
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Nota\footnote{Nota \newpage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: fancyhdr (https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr?lang=en) is an option.

Comment: The standard placement with the `article` class is at the bottom. Can you please show an example of LaTeX code that does not do this?

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: I have added the entire yaml preamble with all the packages used.

Comment: This is not LaTeX code. Not everybody has RMarkdown; what's needed is the *generated* LaTeX code.

Comment: I just included the latex code.

Comment: I don't know if this is a bug or a feature, but Rmarkdown p[aced \newpage INSIDE the footnote.  Maybe add a blank line between the two?

Comment: In the summary code that I have added, it is solved by adding a blank line in rmarkdown before the command ```\newpage```, but in the original (very long) I do not use ```\newpage```.

Comment: I have found the solution, I have added ```\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}``` in the preamble.